# a logit equation

Tags: equations

I am trying to create a logit equation for my paper. I have 12 covariates and thus shortened the equation. With the code below makes a equation number appear below my equation and not on the right side of it. Any help with making this equation more presentable will be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

```
\newline
\begin{equation}
\begin{math}
    \tiny{Pr}(\text{Vote} = 1 | \text{S, P, I}) &= \frac{\text{exp}(\beta_0 + \beta_1 \text{Gender} + \beta_2 \text{Age} + ... \beta_12 \text{immigration)} }{1 + \text{exp}(\beta_0 + \beta_1 \text{Gender} + \beta_2 \text{Age} +... \beta_12 \text{immigration})} \label{eq:glm1} 
\end{math}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: you must get error messages from `\begin{equation}
\begin{math}` but no one can help make an equation fit the page if you do not show how big the page is, Please make a small (10 or so line) but _complete_ document not just a fragment

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newline
\begin{equation}
\begin{math}
    \tiny{Pr}(\text{Vote} = 1 | \text{S, P, I}) &= \frac{\text{exp}(\beta_0 + \beta_1 \text{Gender} + \beta_2 \text{Age} + ... \beta_12 \text{immigration)} }{1 + \text{exp}(\beta_0 + \beta_1 \text{Gender} + \beta_2 \text{Age} +... \beta_12 \text{immigration})} \label{eq:glm1} 
\end{math}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Almost every part of this is in error.

the `\newline` produces

```
! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.
```

The `\begin{math}` produces

```
! LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter.
```

as math mode has already been started by `equation`

`\tiny` produces

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Command \tiny invalid in math mode on input line 6.
```

as size changes are not allowed in math mode

the `&` produces

```
 ! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
```

as you can only have `&` in alignments not in `equation` or `math` environments.

After an error TeX only recovers enough to syntax check the rest of the document, it makes no attempt to make reasonable PDF output.

I also get

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \text
```

but perhaps you had used `amsmath`

---

Perhaps

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
  \operatorname{Pr}(\text{Vote} = 1 \mid \text{S, P, I})\\
 = \frac{\exp(\beta_{0} + \beta_{1} \text{Gender} + \beta_{2} \text{Age} + \dots +
    \beta_{12} \text{immigration)} }{1 + \exp(\beta_{0} + \beta_{1} \text{Gender} + \beta_{2} \text{Age} +
\dots + \beta_{12 }\text{immigration})} \label{eq:glm1} 
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

note subscripts should be marked as `_{...}`

Comment: I think the OP probably wanted `\beta_{12}` either with the meaning twelve, or perhaps more likely one, two

Comment: Mind you, I don't really know either

Comment: Thank you kindly. I tried with 'amsmath' and corrected the errors. However, I am unable to get the number to become subscript that way it reads beta 12 (the 12 in subscript).

Comment: @Rafael As I commented just above you. Indeed it's commonly recommended to always use `_{...}`, even for one character subscripts (e.g. `_{1}`), although you can get away without them for one character subscripts. They are essential if you have more than one character

Comment: @Au101 oops didn't notice that, fixed, thanks

Comment: @Rafael answer updated

Answer (score 1):

Your code was incorrect. One doesn't have to add a `math` environment inside an `equation` environment. Also, don't insert a `newline` before a display equation. For a correct pacing, use `\mid` instead of `|` in this context. Finally, don't code `Pr` a probability: it will appear as the product of ttwo italic variables. Define it as a math operator: it will be typed in roma  and have a correct spacing.

I propose two solutions: one consists in reducing the font size before entering the `equation` environment, the other  keeps the normal font size, but displays the equation on two lines, with a `\shortintertext` command, from `mathtools`. In this case, needless to load `amsmath`, since `mathtools` is an extension thereof.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Prb}{Pr}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.3pt}

\begin{document}

Text text text tex. More text more text more text more text. More text more text more text more text.More text more text more text more text. More text more text more text more text.

{\small\begin{equation}
  \Prb(\text{Vote} = 1 \mid \text{S, P, I}) = \frac{\text{exp}(\beta_0 + \beta_1 \text{Gender} + \beta_2 \text{Age} + ... \beta_{12} \text{immigration)} }{1 + \text{exp}(\beta_0 + \beta_1 \text{Gender} + \beta_2 \text{Age} + ... \beta_{12} \text{immigration})} \label{eq:glm1}
  \end{equation}
}
%%
\begin{gather}
  \shortintertext{\quad$ \Prb(\text{Vote} = 1 \mid \text{S, P, I}) = $} \frac{\text{exp}(\beta_0 + \beta_1 \text{Gender} + \beta_2 \text{Age} + ... \beta_{12} \text{immigration)} }{1 + \text{exp}(\beta_0 + \beta_1 \text{Gender} + \beta_2 \text{Age} + ... \beta_{12} \text{immigration})} \label{eq:glm2}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Happy New Year! @Mico: I promise I'll do my best! This one was particularly rich (about as many unicode-only characters  as pips in a mandarin). And – icing on the cake – whereas I recommended to use `\mid` preferably to`|`, my editor displayed `\mid` as `|` ;o)